# Python 2.7 extracting data from multiple URLs from json api

Tags: python, json

This is the code I use to extract data from multiple URLs.
Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get it to work for multiple URLs in a list.

Any thoughts?

```
import urllib
import re

urls = ("http://pool.webcoin.us/plt/index.php/?page=api&action=getpoolstatus&api_key=0c57173da8c900831fc111003ea636d5c261e79e76b670f3b51a2d325f9b94db",
        "http://uno.coin-pool.org/index.php?page=api&action=getpoolstatus&api_key=f20daa5ea5945c1b9641b81d8dd9f4b556153182c03a2a2a94d7a95abc6dc4f8",
        "http://goat.easy-mining.net/index.php?page=api&action=getpoolstatus&api_key=5d232e86cd1a0cdfdafdcb0722da48c21778d35cd8654f7dbc82202881163df9")

for url in urls:

    source = urllib.urlopen(url)
    regexp = r">(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)<"
    found = 0


    for line in source.readlines():
        if found:
            match = re.search(regexp,line)
            break
        if "networkdiff" in line:
            found = 1



    print match.groups()
```

Comment: So why not try and **loop** and load each url separately? What made you think that `urllib.urlopen()` would support a list argument?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
import urllib
import re

urls = ["http://ffc.coinz.pw/index.php?page=statistics&action=pool",
       "http://pool.webcoin.us/plt/index.php/?page=api&action=getpoolstatus&api_key=0c57173da8c900831fc111003ea636d5c261e79e76b670f3b51a2d325f9b94db",
       "http://uno.coin-pool.org/index.php?page=api&action=getpoolstatus&api_key=f20daa5ea5945c1b9641b81d8dd9f4b556153182c03a2a2a94d7a95abc6dc4f8",
       "http://goat.easy-mining.net/index.php?page=api&action=getpoolstatus&api_key=5d232e86cd1a0cdfdafdcb0722da48c21778d35cd8654f7dbc82202881163df9"]

for url in urls:
    source = urllib.urlopen(url)
    regexp = r">(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)<"
    found = 0

    for line in source.readlines():
        if found:
            match = re.search(regexp,line)
            break
        if "Current Difficulty" in line:
            found = 1

        for link in url(x):
            x += 1



    print match.groups()
```

You have to use loop for each url.

Comment: It didn't work. It only printing out the 1st URL. Not all the URLs in the list.